# TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

Tags: pytorch, named-entity-recognition, transformer-model

I am trying to train a BERT model using PyTorch transformers and CRF in colab and I got error:
TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'

[PHOTO] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpcVD.png)

Could you please help in figuring out the problem

this is my code:

```
class Bert_CRF(BertPreTrainedModel):
def __init__(self, config):
    super(Bert_CRF, self).__init__(config)
    self.num_labels = config.num_labels
    self.bert = BertModel(config)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, self.num_labels)
    self.init_weights()
    self.crf = CRF(self.num_labels, batch_first=True)    

 def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):  # dont confuse this with _forward_alg above.
    outputs = self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask)
    sequence_output = outputs[0]
    sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
    emission = self.classifier(sequence_output)        
    attention_mask = attention_mask.type(torch.uint8)
    if labels is not None:
        loss = -self.crf(log_soft(emission, 2), labels, mask=attention_mask, reduction='mean')
        return loss
    else:
        prediction = self.crf.decode(emission, mask=attention_mask)
        return prediction
```

Comment: Could you please post the remaining code which call the train()?

Comment: I think this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454157/pytorch-bert-typeerror-forward-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-labels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyTorch BERT TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454157/pytorch-bert-typeerror-forward-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-labels)

Comment: def model_init(): return Bert_CRF.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels = len(label_list))

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=8,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    warmup_steps=200,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    save_strategy=IntervalStrategy.EPOCH,
    logging_dir='./logs',
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model_init(),
    args=training_args,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset
)

Comment: This is my train code